# Image Montage + Image Zoomer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to combine two jQuery plugins to make them work together http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/ and http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm

First one automatically makes montage and adds some inline style to img tag. eg. `style="display: inline-block; width: 333px; height: 234px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"`

After that second one is using **width** and **height** properties.
The only problem is that montage script is "filling" the last row when fillLastRow option is true. Because of that it has a bit messy inline style.
`style=display: inline-block; width: 1663px; height: 1075px; left: -1px; top: -443.5px;`

So zoomer script is using "width: 1663px; height: 1075px" values and making the last image's area too large( mouse hover area ), which is blocking some other images.

Is there any way to somehow "trick" zoomer script to make it use the actual visible width and height of the last image? In other words how to get image's visible width and height?